# How to remove tag image below the image gallery from Cincopa plugin in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I have cincopa image gallery on my page. Below this image gallery in wordpress, There is tag image of cincopa saying "Powered by cincopa" and social media images (twitter, facebook). This plugin has one php script page, I am unable to find the code to comment or delete so that the tag image can be hidden or removed. Please help me how can I remove or comment the tag image from that one php file of the cincopa plugin?

Comment: [Cincopa has a premium plan that removes the "powered by" message.](http://www.cincopa.com/cincopamanager/paypal/plans.aspx) Don't be a cheapskate; buy premium, live with the message, or use another product.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oh, that is sad to know. Can you please suggest me any other image gallery plugin for wordpress with the same behavior but without tags that cannot be removed and that are free ?

Comment: I don't know any - I'd work my way through the plugin repository http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Cincopa article explaining the way to remove Cincopa branding
http://help.cincopa.com/entries/444264-How-can-I-remove-the-Powered-By-Cincopa-branding-

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove Cincopa's branding you need to upgrade from a free account to pro account.